# Возвращать количество вызовов метода

Tags: java

Имеется класс Class, который имеет публичный метод `int h()`, который возвращает количество вызовов метода `h` в этом экземпляре (включая происходящий вызов, т.е. первый вызов метода h в данном экземпляре класс вернет 1).

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 6):

```
public class TestClass {
    private int count;
    int h() {
        return ++count;
    }
}
```

Теперь каждый вызов метода у объекта TestClass будет возвращать число на 1 больше, например

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass test = new TestClass();
        System.out.println("Количество вызовов h():" + test.h());
        System.out.println("Количество вызовов h():" + test.h());
    }
```

вернёт:

```
Количество вызовов h():1
Количество вызовов h():2
```

Comment: спасибо, и еще вопрос, если нам нужно не только в этом экземпляре, а в любом другом экземпляре класса?

Comment: @RufaShamikh Почитай о переменных static и private.